# Javascript to extract *.com

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I am looking for a javascript function/regex to extract *.com from a URI... (to be done on client side)

It should work for the following cases:

```
siphone.com = siphone.com
qwr.siphone.com = siphone.com
www.qwr.siphone.com = siphone.com
qw.rock.siphone.com = siphone.com
<http://www.qwr.siphone.com> = siphone.com
```

Much appreciated!

Edit: Sorry, I missed a case:

```
http://www.qwr.siphone.com/default.htm = siphone.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this regex should work for a *few* cases:

```
/[\w]+\.(com|ca|org|net)/
```

I'm not good with JavaScript, but there should be a [library](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri) for splitting URIs out there, right?

According to that link, here's a "strict" regex:

```
/^(?:([^:\/?#]+):)?(?:\/\/((?:(([^:@]*)(?::([^:@]*))?)?@)?([^:\/?#]*)(?::(\d*))?))?((((?:[^?#\/]*\/)*)([^?#]*))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?)/
```

As you can see, you're better off just using the "library". :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var myStrings = [
  'siphone.com',
  'qwr.siphone.com', 
  'www.qwr.siphone.com', 
  'qw.rock.siphone.com', 
  '<http://www.qwr.siphone.com>'
  ];

for (var i = 0; i < myStrings.length; i++) {
    document.write( myStrings[i] + '=' +  myStrings[i].match(/[\w]+\.(com)/gi) + '<br><br>');
}
```

I've placed given demo strings to the **myStrings** array.
i - is index to iterate through this array. **The following line does the matching trick:**

```
myStrings[i].match(/[\w]+\.(com)/gi)
```

and returns the value of siphone.com. If you'd like to match .net and etc. - add (com|net|other) instead of just (com).

Also you may find the following link useful: [Regular expressions Cheat Sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/)

**update:** missed case works too %)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.  I added a few cases for some nonmatches.

```
var cases = [
  "siphone.com",
  "qwr.siphone.com",
  "www.qwr.siphone.com",
  "qw.rock.siphone.com",
  "<http://www.qwr.siphone.com>",
  "hamstar.corm",
  "cheese.net",
  "bro.at.me.come",
  "http://www.qwr.siphone.com/default.htm"];

var grabCom = function(str) {
  var result = str.match("(\\w+\\.com)\\W?|$");
  if(result !== null)
    return result[1];
  return null;
};

for(var i = 0; i < cases.length; i++) {
  console.log(grabCom(cases[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string then search for the `.com` string like so

```
var url = 'music.google.com'
var parts = url.split('.');
for(part in parts) {
    if(part == 'com') {
        return true;
    }
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp to do that. This way modifications to the detections are quite easy.

```
var url = 'www.siphone.com';
var domain = url.match(/[^.]\.com/i)[0];
```

If you use `url.match(/(([^.]+)\.com)[^a-z]/i)[1]` instead. You can assure that the ".com" is not followed by any other characters.

Comment: You don't need to escape the 'dot' when it's in a character class - use `[^.]` rather than `[^\.]`

Comment: Hm, I did not know that. Is it the same for preg? And who the hell downvoted everything? Most answers are perfectly fine?!

Answer (score 0):

```
uri = "foo.bar.baz.com"
uri.split(".").slice(-2).join(".") // returns baz.com
```

This assumes that you want just the hostname and tld.  It also assumes that there is no path information either.

Updated now that you also need to handle uris with paths you could do:

```
uri.split(".").slice(-2).join(".").split("/")[0]
```